# Timezone display value with GMT offset from a given timezone?

Tags: java, timezone

I would like to construct a timezone list to show it to users to select. The display name has to be like:

> `( GMT 5:30 ) India Standard Time(Asia/Calcutta)`

I am taking all timezones with `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()` and constructing the list. The code I wrote is:

```
String[] timeZones = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();
List<String> tzList = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String timeZone : timeZones)
{
  TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone);
  StringBuilder timeZoneStr = new StringBuilder();
  timeZoneStr.append("( GMT ").append(tz.getRawOffset() / (60 * 60 * 1000)).append(" ) ").append(tz.getDisplayName()).append("(").append(timeZone).append(")");
  tzList.add(timeZoneStr.toString());
  System.out.println(timeZoneStr.toString());
}
```

A snippet of the output would be like:

```
( GMT 5 ) Maldives Time(Indian/Maldives)
( GMT 5 ) Pakistan Time(PLT)
( GMT 5 ) India Standard Time(Asia/Calcutta)
( GMT 5 ) India Standard Time(Asia/Kolkata)
( GMT 5 ) India Standard Time(IST)
```

But the output I need to get is:

```
( GMT 5:0 ) Maldives Time(Indian/Maldives)
( GMT 5:0 ) Pakistan Time(PLT)
( GMT 5:30 ) India Standard Time(Asia/Calcutta)
( GMT 5:30 ) India Standard Time(Asia/Kolkata)
( GMT 5:30 ) India Standard Time(IST)
```

What should I do to get 5:30?

Comment: Obviouly you are truncating the minutes in this line `tz.getRawOffset() / (60 * 60 * 1000)` - you need to be slightly more careful. First exctract whole hours then the minutes and concat them.

Comment: @bmorris591, you are absolutely correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A more readable answer is the following:

```
for (String timeZone : timeZones) {
  TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone);

  long hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(tz.getRawOffset());
  long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(tz.getRawOffset())
      - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(hours);

  String timeZoneString = String.format("( GMT %d:%02d ) %s(%s)", hours,
      minutes, tz.getDisplayName(), timeZone);
  tzList.add(timeZoneString);
  System.out.println(timeZoneString);
}
```

This also correctly displays e.g. `5:00` and `5:30`. The use of `String.format()` makes the final string easier to determine when reading the code. The use of the [`TimeUnit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) class simplifies the maths.

Comment: There is one slight display issue when in negative half-hour timezones.  For example, "Pacific/Marquesas" should display as "(GMT -9:30)", usually not "(GMT -9:-30)".  I'd apply Math.abs() to "minutes",
    long minutes = Math.abs(...)

Answer (score 2):

You should switch the timezone forming line to:

```
timeZoneStr.append("( GMT ").append(tz.getRawOffset() / (60 * 60 * 1000)).append(":").append((tz.getRawOffset() / (60 * 1000))%60).append(" ) ").append(tz.getDisplayName()).append("(").append(timeZone).append(")");
```

I think this is the answer you're looking for. However, you may still format the minutes, as they only show one digit when the time offset is, for example 12 hours. It's shown as 12:0.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution with the proper formatting :

```
DateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
fmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

List<String> tzList = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String timeZone : TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()) {   
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone);

    StringBuilder timeZoneStr = new StringBuilder();
    timeZoneStr.append("( GMT ");
    if (tz.getRawOffset() < 0) {
        timeZoneStr.append("-");
    }
    timeZoneStr.append(fmt.format(new Date(Math.abs(tz.getRawOffset()))));
    timeZoneStr.append(" ) ").append(tz.getDisplayName()).append(timeZone).append(")");

    tzList.add(timeZoneStr.toString());
    System.out.println(timeZoneStr.toString());
}
```

Comment: I think the use of a `DateFormat`, while clever, is a little overcomplicated for this problem. If you are using Java 5 or newer, the `TimeUnit` class is very neat. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15363331/474189).

Comment: He wants to format a time, that's exactly the purpose of DateFormat, isn't it?

Comment: I would say an offset is different to a time. Note the extra leg-work you've had to do to account for the potentially negative value of the offset. A time cannot be negative. Anyway, it was just an observation, it's still a clever approach to the problem.

Comment: why "UTC" but printing GMT?

Comment: @ses Because the original poster wanted GMT

Answer (score 0):

Offset timezone using below method :

```
private static String displayTimeZone(TimeZone tz) {

    long hours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(tz.getRawOffset());
    long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(tz.getRawOffset()) 
                              - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(hours);
    // avoid -4:-30 issue
    minutes = Math.abs(minutes);

    String result = "";
    if (hours > 0) {
        result = String.format("(GMT+%d:%02d) %s", hours, minutes, tz.getID());
    } else {
        result = String.format("(GMT%d:%02d) %s", hours, minutes, tz.getID());
    }

    return result;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `SimpleDateFormat` with the `XXX` timezone pattern (produces an ISO 8601 timezone)

```
    DateFormat gmt = new SimpleDateFormat("'GMT' XXX");
    for (TimeZone tz : timeZones) {
        gmt.setTimeZone(tz);
        String gmtTimezone = gmt.format(new Date());
        System.err.println(tz.getID() + " " + gmtTimezone);
    }
```

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#iso8601timezone