# How to get timezone in short in android

Tags: android

I am trying to display a timestamp as "Sat Dec xx ww:yy:zz IST YYYY".
When i run this code snippet in android device i get result as "Sat Dec xx ww:yy:zz GMT+05:30 YYYY".

```
Date dd = new Date();
String s = dd.toString();
```

The below snippet also gives the time in GMT+05:30 format.

```
String timeZone = 
       Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT);
```

TimeZone can be any of the zones as per mob. location. So hard coding doesn't make any sense.
How can i get the result in the desired format?

Answer (score 0):

Use SimpleDateFormat to explicitly get "Sat Dec xx ww:yy:zz" part and "YYYY" part

Store them up in variables

get the time zone String using

```
String timeZone = 
   Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().getID();
```

then use

```
String.format("%s %s %s", firstPart, timeZone, yearPart);
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the qucik reply. But it doesn't solve my problem. I m getting timezone as GMT+05:30. But i want it to be as IST. I don't want to do a hardcode conversion. Any other solutions!!

Comment: In android device with your code it give "Asia/Calcutta" as TimeZone.

Comment: you can refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15362738/timezone-display-value-with-gmt-offset-from-a-given-timezone

There are 3 string representation of the same time zone GMT+5:30, you may need to set the preferred name